# Determine all complex numbers which satisfy conditions - $|z|=2$ $\space$ and $\space$ Im$(z^6)=8$ Im$(z^3)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-geometry

Determine all complex numbers $z$ which satisfy following conditions:

$|z|=2$ $\space$ and $\space$ Im$(z^6)=8$ Im$(z^3)$

I first calculated $z^3$ and $z^6$.

$z^3=x^3-3xy^2+3x^2yi-y^3i$

$z^6=(x+yi)^6=\binom{6}{0}x^6+\binom{6}{1}x^5yi+\binom{6}{2}x^4(yi)^2+\binom{6}{3}x^3(yi)^3+\binom{6}{4}x^2(yi)^4+\binom{6}{5}x(yi)^5+\binom{6}{6}(yi)^6$

$=x^6+6x^5yi+15x^4(-y^2)+20x^3(-y^3i)+15x^2y^4+6xy^5i-y^6$

Then I put imaginary parts in equation Im$(z^6)=8$ Im$(z^3)$ and got following

$6x^5y-20x^3y^3+6xy^5=8(3x^2y-y^3)$

$2xy(x^2-3y^2)\require{cancel} \cancel{(3x^2-y^2)}=8y\require{cancel} \cancel{(3x^2-y^2)}$ (*)

$x(x^2-3y^2)=4$ $\space$ (1)

from $|z|=2$ follows $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=2$ $\space$ $\rightarrow$ $y^2=4-x^2$ (2)

after putting (2) in (1) I got

$x^3-3x=1$

and then $x=2\cos\varphi$

equation $8\cos^3\varphi-6\cos\varphi=1$ can be tranformed to

$2\cos3\varphi=1$ (I got this with help of [identity of $\cos {3x}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8cosx%5E3-6cosx-1%3D0))

and then

$\varphi_1=\frac{\pi}{9}+\frac{2k\pi}{3}$

$\varphi_2=-\frac{\pi}{9}+\frac{2k\pi}{3}$, $\space$ $k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Written differently solution is

$\varphi_1=\frac{\pi}{9}+2k\pi$

$\varphi_2=\frac{5\pi}{9}+2k\pi$

$\varphi_3=\frac{7\pi}{9}+2k\pi$

$\varphi_4=\frac{11\pi}{9}+2k\pi$

$\varphi_5=\frac{13\pi}{9}+2k\pi$

$\varphi_6=\frac{17\pi}{9}+2k\pi$

In line with (*) expresions $3x^2-y^2$ are striked out. We have to include that

$3x^2-y^2=0$

$3x^2-(4-x^2)=0$

$4x^2=4$

$x^2=1$

$(2\cos\varphi)^2=1$

$\cos^2\varphi=\frac{1}{4}$

After solving this equation we get

$\varphi_7=\frac{\pi}{3}+2k\pi$

$\varphi_8=\frac{2\pi}{3}+2k\pi$

$\varphi_9=\frac{4\pi}{3}+2k\pi$

$\varphi_{10}=\frac{5\pi}{3}+2k\pi$

<s>Solution from my textbook:</s>

$\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{z_1=2(\cos\frac{2\pi}{3}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{3})}$<s>.</s>

$\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{z_2=2(\cos\frac{5\pi}{3}+i\sin\frac{5\pi}{3})}$<s>.</s>

$\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{z_3=2(\cos\frac{7\pi}{3}+i\sin\frac{7\pi}{3})}$<s>.</s>

Can someone help me find a mistake?

If you find mistake feel free to edit. On the picture bellow are all 10 solutions.

[image]

Comment: at least 1 mistake: $$(2cos(\phi))^2=1 ; cos^2(\phi)=\frac{1}{4}, cos(\phi)=0.5$$

Comment: @trula Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is shorter to solve with the exponential form of $z$: since its modulus is $2$, we can write $\:z=2\,\mathrm e^{i\theta}$. and the  equation on the imaginary parts becomes $\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im}$
$$\im(z^6)=\im\bigl(64\mathrm e^{6i\theta} \bigr)=64\sin 6\theta,\qquad \im(8z^3)=\im\bigl(64\mathrm e^{3i\theta}\bigr)=64\sin 3\theta$$
whence this simple standard trigonometric equation $\;\sin 6\theta=\sin 3\theta$. Its solutions are
$$ \begin{cases}
6\theta\equiv 3\theta \iff 3\theta\equiv 0\mod 2\pi\iff\theta\equiv 0\mod\frac{2\pi}3,\\
6\theta\equiv \pi-3\theta  \iff 9\theta\equiv \pi \mod 2\pi \iff \theta\equiv \frac\pi 9 \mod\frac{2\pi}9 .
\end{cases}   $$
A short form of the solutions in $\theta$ would be
$$\theta\in\Bigl\{\frac{k\pi}9\,\Bigm|\, k=0, \pm 1,\pm3,\pm 5,\pm 7, 9 \Bigr\}. $$

Answer (score 4):

Without loss of generality, we can reduce the equations to
$$|z|=1 ,\text{Im}(z^6)=\text{Im}(z^3)$$

From this, we can say that when $z=\omega_i$ (where $\omega_i$ are the cube roots of unity), the equations will definitely be true.

After that, use the polynomial expansions for $z^6 $ and $z^3$ considering $z=x+i y$ which is effectively solving $$6xy^{5}\ -20x^{3}y^{3}+6x^{5}y=\left(3yx^{2}-y^{3}\right)$$ upon condition that $$x^2+y^2=1$$ which is a unit circle.

You can access the following graph [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qzlw658psf)

[image]

The intersections of the black graph with the red circle **and** the blue points with coordinates labelled are the solutions required.

Comment: Maybe considering $w = z^3$ should simplify the reasoning.

Comment: Sorry I have read to quickly.  

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi Thank you for your answer. I'm gonna try to to solve this alebraically since this is for advanced high school students

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi Your extra solutions are ok. I think that solution in my textbook is wrong and that I got the right algebraic solution